# Get Author-name from Book-class simple Java

Tags: java

So I am practicing and the simple exercise is to create an Author class, & a Book class.

They have ther getters and setters right(tested), but when I try to get the author-name of a book... it says there is a null object? (Null pointer exception) here is the excerpt of main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Author a = new Author("Julius", "j@gmail.com", 'm');
    Book b = new Book("ASDFG", a, 69.99, 4);

    System.out.println(b.getAuthor().getName());
}
```

I create instances for Author and Book...
and then i say: get the name of author of this book...

I appreciate all help!

Comment: Show us other classes.

Comment: You must set the author field in the constructor of your `Author` class.

Comment: Probably your Book constructor is not setting the author.  Post the source code for Book and we'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've shown, `b.getAuthor()` is returning null.

Meaning you never set the `Author` object in the `Book` class.

You should have a constructor that looks like so (completely guessing on those parameters).

```
private Author author;
// Other fields...

public Book(String title, Author author, double price, int number) {
    this.author = author; // need this
    // other fields = other parameters...
}
```

You will **also** need your `getAuthor()` method to not return null

```
public Author getAuthor() {
    return this.author;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can add try{ } catch(exception){ } to avoid any exception

1. I create the subclass Book and Author
2. In Author, into getname, i add the book( book) ,
3. Add to Author class : **public String getname(){ return "Author :" + name +"  Book:" + bb.book;}**

You can see the code bellow:

```
public class Getauthorname {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Author a = new Author("Julius", "j@gmail.com","m");      
        System.out.println(a.getname());
    }
}

class Author{
    Book bb = new Book("ASDFG", "a", 69.99, 4);
    String name;
    String email;
    String m;

    Author( String name,String email, String m){ 
        this.name= name;
        this.email = email;
        this.m = m;
    }

     public void setname(String name){ this.name= name;   }
     //You must add  to get bb.book or other data you need it
     public String getname(){ return "Author :" + name +"  Book:" + bb.book;}

     public void setemail(String email){ this.email= email;   }
     public String getemail(){ return email;}

     public void setm(String m){ this.m= m;   }
     public String getm(){ return m;}
}

class Book extends Object{  

    String book;
    String a;
    double price;
    int cod;

    Book ( String book,String a, double price, int cod){  
        this.book = book;
        this.a = a;
        this.price = price;
        this.cod = cod; 
    }

     public void setbook(String b){ this.book = book;   }
     public String getbook(){ return book;}

     public void seta(String a){ this.a= a;   }
     public String geta(){ return a;}

     public void seta(double price){ this.price= price;   }
     public double getprice(){ return price;}

     public void setcod(int cod){ this.cod= cod;   }
     public int getcod(){ return cod;}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Author :Julius  Book:ASDFG
```